# Epiphany - Can't login to Google with new google sign-in page

Tags: epiphany, web-browser

From few days ago ever since google rolled out new sign-in page for my account, I can't login to any google service with Epiphany which was my preferred browser. After entering the password I just get stuck with the blank page at https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/password/empty

Things work in Chromium and Firefox.

Looking around the web, there seems to be a bug originally tracked and fixed yesterday at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171770

I'm curious does anyone know when will we get this fix in elementary OS as I'd rather just stick with Epiphany instead of just changing the browser because I can't sign in to google?

Comment: je veux retrouver mon met de passe!

Answer (score 0):

Same for me with web-browser. Easy to fix with
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`